# RichTextBox font changing c#

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I have an issue on my code.
I need to change RichTextBox Font, while keeping the previous text formatting (Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikeout).

My form has RichTextBox; and a ToolStrip containing some ComboBoxes (where I select the Font, and set the Font Format).
Each of the controls above Controls have two events (TextChanged and SelectedIndexChanged) subscribed; running the same line of code:

My RichTextBox HideSelection property is set to false; so I can always see what Font I'm changing to and to prevent my selection from disapearing.

Please find bellow my actual code:

```
private void TcboSize_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtfDirections.SelectionFont = new Font(tcboFonts.Text, (float)Convert.ToDecimal(tcboSize.Text), rtfDirections.SelectionFont.Style);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've moved to the Form Constructor:

```
rtfDirections.HideSelection = false;
```

In order to prevent my RichTextBox Text Selection from Disappearing.

I've subscribed the SelectedIndexChanged on my ComboBoxes; in order to change the Font when the Index changes.
This sets the Font style (including Size) on the RichTextBox, and updates the ComboBox selected Item(s) Text.

My problem:
I wasn't tracking any previous selection.
When dealing with selected text; I should've assigned it to a variable; then make sure the selection is equal to that variable.

I also noticed that (sometimes) when I click any ToolStrip Button; my Text Selection disappears; which should not be the case.
As you can see above; I've set the RichTextBox.HideSelection to false.

I assume that when you select new Text in the RichTextBox; it should over write what was previously selected and use the new selection.
Should I be clearing the ComboBox Selection? If so; how can I accomplish this?

I've put break points on all lines of code and added watches to the selected text; but the Font never changes; unless I clear the Selection, but that way there are no breakpoint hits.

Comment: `rtfDirections.SelectionFont.Style` - you set the same style to the new font.

Comment: Yes.  I did because when you select the font you may have just set the bold, underline and italics.